# How do I get this VBA code to output to a specific number format?

Tags: excel, vba, arr

This is from another answer I received a while back.

[Turn a value range in a cell into a comma separated list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37936337/turn-a-value-range-in-a-cell-into-a-comma-separated-list)

This code below is great stuff, but now I want it to also output each number with 4 digits. So if I get a return of 1,2,3, I want it to return as "0001,0002,0003".

```
Function NumRange(v)
Dim arrC, arr, x As Long, rv As String, sep As String, e

arrC = Split(v, ",")
rv = ""

For Each e In arrC
    If InStr(e, "-") Then
        arr = Split(e, "-")
        arr(0) = Trim(arr(0))
        arr(1) = Trim(arr(1))
        If IsNumeric(arr(0)) And IsNumeric(arr(1)) Then
            For x = CLng(arr(0)) To CLng(arr(1))
                rv = rv & sep & x
                sep = ","
            Next x
        End If
    ElseIf IsNumeric(e) Then
        rv = rv & sep & CLng(e)
        sep = ","
    End If
Next e
NumRange = rv
End Function
```

Comment: Just use the `Format` function in your concatenation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little brute-force, but you could use a variant of this handy translation of the `LPAD` or `PadLeft()` function/method:

[Any method equivalent to PadLeft/PadRight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060347/any-method-equivalent-to-padleft-padright)

```
Function NumRange(v)
  Dim arrC, arr, x As Long, rv As String, sep As String, e

  arrC = Split(v, ",")
  rv = ""

  For Each e In arrC
    If InStr(e, "-") Then
        arr = Split(e, "-")
        arr(0) = Trim(arr(0))
        arr(1) = Trim(arr(1))
        If IsNumeric(arr(0)) And IsNumeric(arr(1)) Then
            For x = CLng(arr(0)) To CLng(arr(1))
                rv = rv & sep & Right("0000" & x, 4)
                sep = ","
            Next x
        End If
    ElseIf IsNumeric(e) Then
        rv = rv & sep & Right("0000" & e, 4)
        sep = ","
    End If
  Next e
  NumRange = rv
End Function
```

Now a cell that contains the formula:

```
=NumRange("1-10")
```

Will contain:

```
001,002,003,004,005,006,007,008,009,010
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple function to format an integer:

```
Function PadLeft(Value, FillerChar, Size) 
    PadLeft = Right(String(Size, FillerChar) + cStr(Value), Size)
End Function
```

Example of use

```
Dim StringToPrint = PadLeft(7, "0", 4)
' StringToPrint value is now "0007"
```

Comment: Not sure why you got a downvote, but this is pretty nice solution because it's scalable.  If I could offer one alternative, the use of the `&` concatenation operator might preclude the necessity to cast the `Value` variable as a string:  `LeftFill = Right(String(Size, FillerChar) & Value, Size)`